# wordpress nav css lost

Tags: css, wordpress

I have built a website on local and it is working perfectly.
but when I upload it to my domain the nav style do not work and in my console I have the folowing error:
localhost:10010/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/assets/css/widget-nav-menu.min.css:1 Failed to load resource

I understand that it is still reading the file from local and when I change the URL to my domain  name instead of local I can open the CSS file.

but I don not know where else I have to change it I did change it on my WordPress settings and on my database on php-admain and still could not fix it and i don not know where it reads this local from ?
I am using FOTON template.
how can I fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Most issues like this are due to URLs getting saved in the DB. Depending on how you are moving it a URL search-replace needs to be done.

However, most plugin issues can be fixed like that also by disabling/re-enabling the plugin or resaving a settings page.

Elementor saves some of the build data as serialized data. Most search-replace functions do not find/update this. They actually have a setting to handle it

**Per their docs:**
To access this tool, go to Elementor → Tools. Then, click on the Replace URL tab.

Enter your old domain name in the box on the left and your new domain name in the box on the right. Then, click Replace URL:

Also double check that the site URL is correct in the admin settings.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, I would highly recommend using a well-trusted, tried and true plugin: [All-in-One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/)

Active installations: 4+ million.

It should take care of most of the DB links automatically for you (not in custom files though, like .css or .js (if hard-coded).  I have been using it for many years and it just makes life easier.  :)

(I am not sure about how it will handle the port number, but I am guessing it should work just fine as well.)

Another method is to do a search and replace:  [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/)

Active Installations: 1+ Million

With this one, you can search and replace a string in any or all tables you wish.  You can even do a test run first to see how many it flags before making any actual changes. Like the other, this is just for the database (DB) as well.

Overall, I prefer the first, but have come across some pretty hairy situations where there were multiple migrations that has different domains names all over the place (don't see it often, but in that case, the first method will only take the backup domain and change to the new and not the other domains names).